# How to use nested object data on ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, axios, jsx

> ***I ADDED ANSWER IN COMMENT***

**I created POST using Node.js. I passed data looks like this in Postman.**

> {
>       "quantity":20,
>       "with_tax":{
>             "price":200,
>             "currency":"lkr"
>         }    }

**I created `<div>` like this(in Movie.jsx class)**

```
 render() {
    return (
      <div className="card" style={{ width: "25rem" }}>
        <form onSubmit={this.props.onPostData}>
```

**with tax price div**

```
    <div
                className="wrap-input100 validate-input bg1"
                data-validate="Please Type Running Time"
              >
                <span className="label-input100">With Tax Price</span>
                <input
                  type="number"
                  name="with_tax_price"
                  placeholder="With Tax Price"
                  className="form-control"
                  onChange={this.props.onDataChange}
                />
              </div>
```

**with tax currency div**

```
              <div
                className="wrap-input100 validate-input bg1"
                data-validate="Please Type Running Time"
              >
                <span className="label-input100">With Tax Currency</span>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="with_tax_currency"
                  placeholder="With Tax Currency"
                  className="form-control"
                  onChange={this.props.onDataChange}
                />
              </div>
```

**in render method I called Movie class like this,(in Movies.jsk class)**

```
class Movies extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
```

**this.state**

```
    this.state = {
      with_tax_price: "",
      with_tax_currency: "",
      quantity: ""
    };
  }
```

**dataChange**

```
  dataChange(ev) {
    this.setState({
      [ev.target.name]: ev.target.value
    });
  }
```

**postData**

```
  postData(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    const with_tax_price = this.state.with_tax_price;
    const with_tax_currency = this.state.with_tax_currency;
    var with_tax;
    const quantity = this.state.quantity;

    this.setState({
      loading: true
    });
```

**data variable**

```
    const data = {
      with_tax: { with_tax_price, with_tax_currency },
      quantity
    };
```

**axios POST**

```
    axios
      .post(apiEndpoint, data)
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

**render method**

```
  render() {
    return (
      <Movie
        onPostData={this.postData.bind(this)}
        onDataChange={this.dataChange.bind(this)}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CHANGE MY CODE INTO THIS,

**in postData(ev)**

```
{ 
ev.preventDefault();
         const with_tax = {
              price: this.state.with_tax_price,
              currency: this.state.with_tax_currency
            };
        }
```

**data variable**

```
 const data = {
      with_tax,
      quantity
    };
```